# How to get rid of DOUBLE dual boot screen

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu20.04 and Windows10 OS on my laptop. The problem is that I don't know the right way to get rid of one out of two dual boot screen. Each OS displays their own dual boot screen and I want just one. Last time I had tried to solve this problem, I caused fail in booting Ubuntu 14.10 in a way that mbr file was corrupted and couldn't repair it by no means, so that's way I seek help this time.
Important BIOS settings are adjusted as follows:
a) boot mode is on LEGACY
b) fast boot option is OFF

I would appreciate any useful advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! How do your boot screens look like? Could you [edit] your question to [show screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post), for example?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the boot order in BIOS .